# Why are environment variables not updating within FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a batch file that is scanning a file `URLs.txt` and for each url run it and download the file. The issue I have is the environment variable within the FOR loop. I am using **cat**, **sed** and **awk** to get the last two parts of the the url so I can provide the filename. The issue is the environment variable is never updated after the first run. I can see that `tmp2.txt` just updated correctly for every url, but the batch file is not updating `outfile` and thus I keep overwriting the first file.

I tried to simplify the batch file for a test and any variable within a for loop never seems to update.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (URLs.txt) do (
    echo %%A > tmp.txt
    cat tmp.txt | sed "s/\(.*\)\//\1_/" | awk -F "/" "{print $NF}" > tmp2.txt
    set /p outfile=<tmp2.txt
    echo Varible A
    echo %%A
    echo.
    echo Varible outfile
    echo %outfile%
    call curl.exe -o %outfile% -u username:password --insecure %%A
    pause
)
```

Why is environment variable `outfile` not updated within FOR loop?

Comment: Ah, the classic "you're using delayed expansion, but you're not _using_ delayed expansion." It happens more than you might think.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo !outfile!
```

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

In your case, since `outfile` is assigned the value `%%A`, you can replace `%outfile%` with `%%A` - and it would be an idea to `"quote the string"` anyway since `"quoting a string"` makes it a single token rather than a series - just in case your filenames contain separators like <kbd>Space</kbd>