# Windows Batch Files - Moving/Getting For Loop Variables

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to simply get the filenames from a directory into a loop and then process (with the eventual aim of then doing a substring on the filename), but can't get it to work.

I've googled plenty and it seems to me that what I'm doing should work, but I'm obviously missing something.

Here's my code:-

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set files=*.*
FOR %%A IN ("%files%") DO (
  echo %%A
  Set MYVAR=%%A
  echo MYVAR=%MYVAR%
)
pause
```

The `echo` of the `%%A` works fine, but `MYVAR` is always empty.  I had this working 
on 1 line earlier, before I added the brackets.

Please help.  I've spent far too long on this already and am pulling my hair out.

Comment: [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Thanks.  That was helpful in realising I need to use !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are environment variables not updating within FOR loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335392/why-are-environment-variables-not-updating-within-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one of the two methods below.

Either:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "files=*.*"
For %%A In ("%files%") Do (
    Echo=%%A
    Set "MYVAR=%%A"
    Echo=MYVAR=!MYVAR!
)
Timeout -1
```

Or:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "files=*.*"
For %%A In ("%files%") Do (
    Echo=%%A
    Set "MYVAR=%%A"
    Call Echo=MYVAR=%%MYVAR%%
)
Timeout -1
```

Comment: Thanks.  Using ! instead of % worked.   I don't seem to need the Timeout -1 though.  What's that for?

Comment: You used `pause`, `timeout` is effectively a similar command with a little more control, type `Timeout /?` for more information, you can of course use either!

Comment: oh, okay, got you.  Thanks.