# an error with set /a in a loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this code:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set count=0
set letter=a,b,c
for %%a in (%letter%) do (
set /a "count+=1"
echo %count%
)
pause
```

The output is:

> ```
> 0
> 0
> 0
> ```

I want that the output will be:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> ```

I also tried to do it without `EnableDelayedExpansion`, but I had no luck. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are environment variables not updating within FOR loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335392/why-are-environment-variables-not-updating-within-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to

```
echo !count!
```

with delayedexpansion

or

```
call echo %%count%%
```

`%count%` will always return the value of `count` as it stood when the block (parenthesised series of statements) was encountered.